# Navegação por Setas em Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, autocompletar

Estou fazendo um autocomplete em `jquery` e `ajax`,
os resultados obtidos pelo `ajax` eu vou colocando em `<div>`.

Gostaria que o usuário pudesse navegar com a seta pelos resultados, saindo do `<input>` e navegado pela `<div>`.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "PartServlet.class.php?action=getArray&keys[stats]=Utilizavel&keys[name]="+word
}).done(function(list){
  if(list.result === 1){
    var buffer = "";
    $.each(list.obj, function(index,part){
      part = $.parseJSON(part);
      buffer += "<div class='partItem' data-id='"+part.id+"' data-name='"+part.name+"'>"+part.id+"-"+part.name+"</div>";
    });
    $("#autocomplete").html(buffer).css("display", "block");
  }
  ajaxRunning = false; 
}).fail(function (data){
  ajaxRunning = false;
  $("#autocomplete").html("").css("display","none");
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
  <div id="autocomplete">
  </div>
</div>
```